# String matching query in flutterfire firestore

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all records having a particular email value. Here `email1` is user provided.

I have tried :

```
QuerySnapshot userList = await  users!.where('email', '>=', email1).where('email', '<=', email1).get(); \\ gives syntax error

users!.where("email", isGreaterThan: email1).get(); \\ returns all records

users!.where("email", isGreaterThan: email1).where("email", isLessThan: email1).get(); \\ returns no record

users!.where('email', arrayContainsAny: [email1]).get() \\ returns no record
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `isEqualTo`:

```
users!.where("email", isEqualTo: email1).get();
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine. I also realized that I was mistakenly storing another field in email.